# Using Jquery function 's argument to run different result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using 2 functions to hide and show all different divs in my html. I'm trying to pass a parameter into the function and use if condition to hide or show different div.

Here is my Jquery Hide function

```
function HideDivs(content){
   if(content==="list"){
       $("div#temp_block").hide();
   }else if(content==="midbtn"){
       $(".search_midbtns").hide();
   }else if(content==="result"){
       $(".search_result").hide();
   }else if(content==="edit"){
       $("#edit_data").hide();
   }

}
```

and i am using it inside the document ready function

```
HideDivs("result");
HideDivs("midbtns");
```

but i can't hide these divs. Is there a way to do this ? I am having so many div to hide and show. Hope this would be a better way to view the js code.

Comment: provide code on fiddle

Comment: also please use camelCase naming regular functions

Comment: sorry. the reason I did not put code on fiddle is its a part of long Js file.  just trying to replace all the $("#id").hide() to more a obivious function

Answer (score 1):

Check your strings `"midbtns" !== "midbtn"` also check that your class names match.

Comment: also thinks its the problem.. note to future if you read this comment, use object enums to handle this kind of things more safetly. for example : var listType = "list" , and than you always use this object. ofc if you are using _prototype function it will be easier to define it as class vaiable. if you didnt get me, just use it as a global page parameter. better code to read and less bugs to have :)